# How can I check if azure stoarge account has a tag with name that starts with "ABC"

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to create a azure policy that blocks resources from having tag that start's with "ABC".

POLICY

```
"parameter" :{
   "tagname":{
      "type":"string",
      "defaultValue":"ABC"
   }
},

"policyRule" :{
    "if" : {
        "allOf" : [
           {
              "field":"type",
              "equals":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
           },
           {
               "field":"[concat('tags[', parameter('tagname'), '*', ']')]",
               "exists":true
           }
        ]
    },
    "then":{
        "effect":"deny"
    }
}
```

Can we use regular expressions like "ABC*" to get tags that starts with ABC in tagname

Comment: did you tested the policy you designed? did you get any error?
For my understanding, if you need to block resources starting with "ABC", you should deine:
"defaultValue":"^ABC"

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagname'), ']')]",
            "like": "ABC*"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagname": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, the above solution actually checks for Tag value like "ABC*" and not Tagname "ABC*". Here it is checking for tag named "ABC" and in like condition it is evaluating value of the tag and not the name

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a azure policy that blocks resources from having tag that start's with "ABC".

Here is the updated policy to block the **Tag** name start with **ABC**.

```
 {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "tags",
              "exists": "true"
            },
            {
              "field": "tags['ABC']",
              "exists": "true"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {}
    }
```

Policy is denying **Resource Group** creation if I enter the `Tag` name **"ABC"**

[image]

Comment: Hello, the above solution you mentioned works for tag name ABC but what I am looking for is tagname that starts with ABC. Suppose I have a tag name ABC-xxx I want my policy to block any tag that startsWith "ABC"

Comment: Check this policy,if you want to block tag name start with ABC.
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "exists": "true"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags",
          "condition": "startsWith",
          "value": "ABC"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}

Comment: I think  { "field": "tags", "condition": "startsWith", "value": "ABC" }  is invalid syntax for policy definition rule